# Syntax to reference a file which is in the same folder as the file you are currently working on

Tags: html, syntax, tags, relative-path

Q. Using relative referencing, what syntax would you use to reference a file called image.gif
which is in the same folder (named pass2) as the file you are currently working on?

A.

```
<img src ="image.gif">
```

B.

```
<img src="/image.gif">
```

C.

```
<img src="pass2/image.gif">
```

D.

```
<img src="/pass2/image.gif">
```

I will select option A because I am working on the same folder. So, no need to change the folders from the root. But there is no answers so can't verify this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the image is in the same folder  , then you can use below

```
<img src="image.gif" alt="My test image">
```

[From MDN :](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/Dealing_with_files)

> To link to a target file in the same directory as the invoking HTML file, just use the filename, e.g. my-image.jpg.
>
> To reference a file in a subdirectory, write the directory name in front of the path, plus a forward slash, e.g. subdirectory/my-image.jpg.
>
> To link to a target file in the directory above the invoking HTML file, write two dots. So for example, if index.html was inside a subfolder of test-site and my-image.jpg was inside test-site, you could reference my-image.jpg from index.html using ../my-image.jpg.
>
> You can combine these as much as you like, for example ../subdirectory/another-subdirectory/my-image.jpg.

[For More](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp)